# como imprimir o acceder a los elemento de un json de php con ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

buenos dias esta es mi primera consulta: tengo el siguiente codigo JS

```
`$(document).ready(function(e) {
    
    $('#agregarCarrito').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert("hola");
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var nombre = $(this).data('nombre');
        var img = $(this).data('img');
        var carpeta = $(this).data('carpeta');
        var rubro = $(this).data('rubro');
        var cantidad = $('#cantidad_prod').val();
        let formData = new FormData();
            
        formData.append('id',id);
        formData.append('nombre',nombre);
        formData.append('img',img);
        formData.append('carpeta',carpeta);
        formData.append('cantidad',cantidad);
        formData.append('rubro',rubro);
         $.ajax({
                        url: 'consultasAjax/agregar_carrito.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: formData,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(response) {
                            var cantidad_prod = Object.keys(response).length;
                            $('#badge_c_compras').text(cantidad_prod);
                            console.log(response+"/////"+cantidad_prod);
                            response.forEach(element => {
                                $('#carritoCompras').append(
                                    `
                                        <a href="panelTienda.php?departamento=detalle_p&id=${element['id']}&rubro=${element['rubro']}" class="dropdown-item">
                                        <!-- Message Start -->
                                        <div class="media">
                                          <img src="dist/images/${element['carpeta']}/${element['img']}" >
                                          <div class="media-body">
                                            <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                                              ${element['nombre']}
                                              <span class="float-right text-sm text-danger"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                            </h3>
                                            <p class="text-sm">Cantidad: ${element['cantidad']}</p>
                                            <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Message End -->
                                      </a>
                                     <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    `
                                );
                            });
                        }
        });
        
        
        
    });
});`
Y ESTE ES EL PHP QUE CONSULTA: `<?php 
    $productos=unserialize(isset($_COOKIE['productos'])?$_COOKIE['productos']:'');

    if (is_array($productos)==false) {
        $productos=array();
    }
    $existeProducto=false;
    foreach ($productos as $key => $value) {
        if($value['id']==$_REQUEST['id']){
            $productos[$key]['cantidad']+=$_REQUEST['cantidad'];
            $existeProducto=true;
        }
    }

    if ($existeProducto==false) {
        $nuevo_producto=array(
            "id"=>$_REQUEST['id'],
            "nombre"=>$_REQUEST['nombre'],
            "img"=>$_REQUEST['img'],
            "carpeta"=>$_REQUEST['carpeta'],
            "cantidad"=>$_REQUEST['cantidad'],
            "rubro"=>$_REQUEST['rubro']
        );
        array_push($productos, $nuevo_producto);
    }

    setcookie("productos",serialize($productos));
    echo json_encode($productos);


?>`
```

el problema es qeu quiero acceder a cada uno de estos valores de forma separada pero me sale el siguiente error en consola.

esto es lo que me devuelve el response: [{"id":"124466","nombre":"FRUTERO 19324 DE VIDRIO","img":"FRUTERO 19324 DE VIDRIO.jpg","carpeta":"cristaleria","cantidad":"1","rubro":"CRISTALERIA"}]/////149

el resultado de esta linea -> var cantidad_prod = Object.keys(response).length; es : 149
segun el tutorial que estoy siguiendo me dice que deberia de entregarme la CANTIDAD elementos u objetos que seria en este caso 1.

y el otro problema es que al hacer el foreach me salta el siguiente error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: response.forEach is not a function
    at Object.success (VM501 surtiplast.js:30)
    at c (VM502 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM502 jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (VM502 jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM502 jquery.min.js:2)
```

espero me puedan ayudar en lo que estoy haciendo mal y disculpen lo largo pero es mi primer post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás recibiendo es una cadena que necesitar convertir a objeto. Usar Object.keys() en una cadena, tratará cada caracter como propiedad (o elemento), por eso es que obtienes 149:

```js
let response = '[{"id":"124466","nombre":"FRUTERO 19324 DE VIDRIO","img":"FRUTERO 19324 DE VIDRIO.jpg","carpeta":"cristaleria","cantidad":"1","rubro":"CRISTALERIA"}]';

// Estás recibiendo una cadena
console.log(Object.keys(response).length);

// Debes convertir a JSON
response = JSON.parse(response);
// Ahora ya funciona
console.log(Object.keys(response).length);
```

Por defecto, las peticiones AJAX de jQuery, deberían intentar "adivinar" el tipo de dato recibido, es raro que te esté devolviendo una cadena, pero puedes especificar qué quieres recibir en la respuesta:

```
     $.ajax({
                    url: 'consultasAjax/agregar_carrito.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    // Especifica que quieres recibir un objeto JSON
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        // El resultado debe ser un objeto JSON
                        console.log(response);
                        // Aquí todo el resto de tu código
                    }
    });
```

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad que no me imagine ese pequeño detalle jeje! ya me funciona como esperaba. mil gracias de verdad